# Error while taking Gradle build for spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have below the gradle configuration file for the spring boot application  and getting an  error  while building the project

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.14.RELEASE'
    // Add git release plugin for versioning snapshots and release builds
    id 'pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release' version '1.10.1'
    // Add Git properties plugin, added for the actuator
    id 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties' version '1.5.2'
}
 
repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}


group 'com.xx'
project.version = scmVersion.version
project.ext.timestamp = new Date().format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

// Customize Git properties plugin added for the actuator
gitProperties {
    // Change date format in git.properties file.
    dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
    dateFormatTimeZone = 'GMT'
}

scmVersion {
    repository {
        directory = project.rootProject.file('.')
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.14.RELEASE'
    compile 'io.zipkin.java:zipkin-autoconfigure-ui:2.6.1'
    compile 'io.zipkin.java:zipkin-server:2.6.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.5.14.RELEASE'
}


tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

war {
    enabled = true
 }
 
 // Spring Boot 1
bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'com.xx.sleuth.api.ZipkinServerApplication'
    classifier = 'boot'
    enabled = true
}

processResources {
    filter ReplaceTokens, tokens:[BUILD_VERSION: project.version, BUILD_TIMESTAMP: project.ext.timestamp]
}
```

while running the gradle command  `**gradlew clean build**`

I am getting below error

C:\Projects\Git_Repo\zipkin>gradlew clean build
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'zipkin-server'.
 Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskInputs.file(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs;
```

**The version used is**

- The gradle version used is:- **6.7.1** java version:- **1.8** Spring
  boot version:- **1.5.14**